# Modify .htaccess to allow existing files without extension to be served

Tags: apache, htaccess

I have the following .htaccess:

```
#If the requested URI does not end with an extension OR if the URI ends with .php*
#(where * is optionally one or more numbers)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php[s0-9]*$ [NC]

#Then serve the URI via the mapper
RewriteRule .* /mapper.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

I would like to add the following conditions to it:

- The file actually exists
- And is without an extension

So the entire file would do something like this:

```
IF (requested URI does not end with an extension) OR (URI ends with .php*) THEN
    rewrite the URI
END

IF (file exists) AND (file requested does not end with an extension)
    rewrite the URI
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php[s0-9]*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /mapper.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /mapper.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, it's not working.... What is the -s? For files it's not -f?

Comment: `-s` is for a file with size (ie. not empty) `-f` is for any file. [See documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: Thanks! Your example showed me that we ca use many RewriteRule with [L]!